# How can I re-ordered the value of a column with some condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

See the last two row where **option_order** is 0 but **type** is different. I want to keep them on first position for each **type**. How can I re-ordered the value of **option_order** column?

Here, the condition is, the '000' **choice** must be kept on first for each **type** by setting its position_order.

**current table status:**

**MULTIPLE_CHOICE** Table

```
id  choice  type  option_order
1    AA      1       1
2    BB      1       2
3    CC      1       3
4    AAA     2       4
5    BBB     2       5
6    CCC     2       6
7    DDD     2       7
8    000     1       0
9    000     2       0
```

**Required updated table:**
This is what I need:

updated  **MULTIPLE_CHOICE** Table

```
id  choice  type  option_order
8    000     1       1
1    AA      1       2
2    BB      1       3
3    CC      1       4
9    000     2       5
4    AAA     2       6
5    BBB     2       7
6    CCC     2       8
9    DDD     2       9
```

The actual table is too big, so I cannot do this by edit. Please help for this complex query. I have no clue to solve this.

**[Note: I need this to solve for mysql version 5.7]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recalculate the whole column. Use, for example, user-defined variable:

```sql
UPDATE MULTIPLE_CHOICE
SET option_order = (@counter := @counter + 1)
WHERE (SELECT @counter := 0) = 0
ORDER BY type, choice;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3b4d2edc41a59be403f065b6c001b69d)

---

> can you explain this condition: `WHERE (SELECT @counter := 0) = 0`. – HiddenHopes

This is a condition only formally - as you can see it is always TRUE. The aim of this construction is in variable initialization.

In SELECT queries we can initialise user-defined variables in separate subquery cross-joined to another tables, like:

```
SELECT {columnset}
FROM {tableset}
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @variable := starting_value ) AS initialize_variables
{the rest clauses}
```

But we cannot do the same in UPDATE. The calculations are critically dependent by rows processing order, i.e. `ORDER BY` clause with the ordering expression which provides rows uniqueness is compulsory. But the subquery which initializes the variables will convert single-table UPDATE to multiple-table which does not support ORDER BY clause at all!

The way out of this situation is to initialize the variable in WHERE clause. When server builds query execution plan it evaluates all constant expressions, including ones in WHERE clause. Moreover, in UPDATE server MUST evaluate WHERE expression before updating because it must firstly determine the rows which will be updated, and only then update them. So the expression in WHERE will be evaluated before rows updating, and hence the variable will be initialized before rows iteration with guarantee.

Comment: can you explain this condition: WHERE (SELECT @counter := 0) = 0. Thanks for your great support.

Comment: @HiddenHopes I add the explanations.

Comment: I think putting the variable assignment in the `where` is very dangerous.  There is no guarantee that it will not be evaluated for each row -- and that is particularly true if there are other conditions in the `where`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Before updating server must select rows which will be updated, is it? checking during update, tablescan, is expensive... But for to select rows for updating server must evaluate WHERE... *There is no guarantee that it will not be evaluated for each row* Server is smart enough for to detect that the subquery is not correlated, i.e. is a constant. We may even convert this subquery to an expression: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=953c4f72cdc64a947d32e52833d9880f